# How to provide tooltip for any AEM RTE pulgin icon in touch UI?

Tags: aem, rte

How to provide tooltip for any AEM 6.1 (SP1) RTE pulgin icon in touch UI?
@rakhi4110

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have tried adding the property "fieldDescription - string- value" but it cloud not work. tried with giving  "text" as well but couldn't get the tooltip.

Comment: Maybe you should add all this and some code in your question and explain what you expect to work and what's not working for you. Be specific.

Comment: I have added below code in Plugin.js, but this is not working, what I wanted to do is that I have RTE plugin for text component in which their are so many icons like Table,List,Link,Rows,Column... now I want to add the tooltip which can show me the message when I hover the mouse on any icon then it should be like, if I am hovering on Table icon then message should be "Table" & same for other icons as well.

Comment: The code which I was adding to plugin.js                                                            :             pluginConfig = pluginConfig || { };
   var defaults = {
                "tooltips": "title": "To Upper Case" {
                    "touchuitouppercase": {
                        "title": "To Upper Case",
                        "text": "To Upper Case"
                    }
                }
            };
           CUI.rte.Utils.applyDefaults(pluginConfig, defaults);
     this.config = pluginConfig;
        }

Comment: Can any one please help me on this issue.?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at my answer on this question, it should help you out in configuring your RTE. btw menu tooltips are OOTB.

[AEM 6.1 - Configure Rich Text Editor Plugins on an RTE field inside a Touch UI Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44182298/aem-6-1-configure-rich-text-editor-plugins-on-an-rte-field-inside-a-touch-ui-d)