# AEM 6.1 - Configure Rich Text Editor Plugins on an RTE field inside a Touch UI Dialog

Tags: aem, custom-component

I have a Touch UI dialog containing multiple Rich Text fields. Some are spread out over several tabs. I would like to add several plugins, such as the misctools plugin, to the RTE toolbar. How is this accomplished?

I have tried configuring them using the an rtePlugins node as a child of the field node in the dialog, as well as adding an rtePlugins node under the cq:editConfig->cq:inplaceEditing node, but none of these approaches change the RTE toolbar inside the dialog itself (I don't want in-place editing).

Is what I want to do even possible?

Comment: This could be a problem with the `uiSettings` node, similar to what's described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956596/adding-styles-in-rich-text-touch-ui-multifield/42181671#42181671

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE TO MY PREVIOUS ANSWER:

HAVE A LOOK AT THIS https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/administer/operations/page-authoring/rich-text-editor.html #RTE - In-place and In a Dialog

It would appear RTE inside a dialog is actually possible, but it does have it's issues, as documented in the link above. Additionally, 6.3 now uses CoralUI2, so this solution above does work, but the setting of useFixedInlineToolbar="{Boolean}true" has no affect inside a dialog, the RTE menu is not visible until you click inside the RTE textarea. I'm yet to resolve this.

Here's an example I've just created for RTE inside a touchUI dialog in AEM6.3

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    jcr:title="Properties"
    sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog">
    <content
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
        <layout
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"/>
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <column
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <regulartext
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                            fieldLabel="Text"
                            name="./regulartext"/>
                    <text jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                              sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog/richtext"
                              fieldLabel="RICH As Text"
                              name="./text"
                              useFixedInlineToolbar="{Boolean}true">
                        <rtePlugins jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <edit
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    defaultPasteMode="wordhtml"
                                    features="[cut,copy,paste-plaintext,paste-wordhtml]"
                                    stripHtmlTags="{Boolean}true"/>
                            <findreplace
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    features="*"/>
                            <format
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    features="*"/>
                            <image
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    features="*"/>
                            <justify
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    features="*"/>
                            <links jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                <linkDialogConfig
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        height="{Long}316">
                                    <linkAttributes jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                        <linkAdvanced
                                                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                                collapsed="{Boolean}true"
                                                collapsible="{Boolean}true"
                                                inputValue="advanced"
                                                name="./linkdialog/cq:adhocLinkTrackingTab"
                                                title="Link tracking"
                                                xtype="dialogfieldset">
                                            <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                                <enable
                                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                        attribute="enabletracking"
                                                        fieldDescription="override analytics framework settings"
                                                        fieldLabel="Custom link tracking"
                                                        name="./linkdialog/cq:adhocLinkTrackingEnableTracking"
                                                        xtype="checkbox">
                                                    <listeners
                                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                            check="function(component){var dlg=component.findParentByType('rtelinkdialog');dlg.enableSCFields(component.checked);}"/>
                                                </enable>
                                                <events
                                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                        attribute="adhocevents"
                                                        fieldDescription="e.g.: event2, event7"
                                                        fieldLabel="Include SiteCatalyst events"
                                                        name="./linkdialog/cq:adhocLinkTrackingEvents"
                                                        xtype="textfield"/>
                                                <evars
                                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                        attribute="adhocevars"
                                                        fieldDescription="e.g.: eVar1: pagedata.url, prop4: 'const'"
                                                        fieldLabel="Include SiteCatalyst variables"
                                                        name="./linkdialog/cq:adhocLinkTrackingEvars"
                                                        xtype="textfield"/>
                                            </items>
                                        </linkAdvanced>
                                    </linkAttributes>
                                </linkDialogConfig>
                            </links>
                            <lists
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    features="*"/>
                            <misctools
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    features="*">
                                <specialCharsConfig jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                    <chars jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                        <copyright
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                entity="©"/>
                                        <trademark
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                entity="™"/>
                                        <registered
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                entity="®"/>
                                        <emDash
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                entity="—"/>
                                        <dagger
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                entity="†"/>
                                        <doubleDagger
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                entity="‡"/>
                                    </chars>
                                </specialCharsConfig>
                            </misctools>
                            <paraformat
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    features="*">
                                <formats jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                    <p
                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                            description="Paragraph"
                                            tag="p"/>
                                    <h1
                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                            description="Heading 1"
                                            tag="h1"/>
                                    <h2
                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                            description="Heading 2"
                                            tag="h2"/>
                                    <h3
                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                            description="Heading 3"
                                            tag="h3"/>
                                    <h4
                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                            description="Heading 4"
                                            tag="h4"/>
                                    <h5
                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                            description="Heading 5"
                                            tag="h5"/>
                                    <h6
                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                            description="Heading 6"
                                            tag="h6"/>
                                </formats>
                            </paraformat>
                            <spellcheck
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    features="*"
                                    invalidStyle="background-color: #ffdddd;"/>
                            <styles
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    features="*">
                                <styles jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                    <disclaimer
                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                            cssName="small"
                                            text="Disclaimer"/>
                                </styles>
                            </styles>
                            <subsuperscript
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    features="*"/>
                            <table
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    features="*"/>
                            <undo
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    features="*"/>
                        </rtePlugins>
                        <htmlRules jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <docType jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                <typeConfig
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        useSemanticMarkup="{Boolean}true"/>
                            </docType>
                        </htmlRules>
                        <uiSettings jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <cui jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                <inline
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        toolbar="[#format,-,#justify,-,#lists,-,links#modifylink,links#unlink,links#anchor,-,#styles,#paraformat,-,subsuperscript#subscript,subsuperscript#superscript,-,edit#cut,edit#copy,edit#paste-plaintext,edit#paste-wordhtml,-,findreplace#find,findreplace#replace,-,undo#undo,undo#redo,-,spellcheck#checktext,-,misctools#specialchars,-,#styles,#paraformat,-,table#table]">
                                    <popovers jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                        <format
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                items="[format#bold,format#italic,format#underline]"
                                                ref="format"/>
                                        <justify
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                items="[justify#justifyleft,justify#justifycenter,justify#justifyright]"
                                                ref="justify"/>
                                        <lists
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                items="[lists#unordered,lists#ordered,lists#outdent,lists#indent]"
                                                ref="lists"/>
                                        <styles
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                items="styles:getStyles:styles-pulldown"
                                                ref="styles"/>
                                        <paraformat
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                items="paraformat:getFormats:paraformat-pulldown"
                                                ref="paraformat"/>
                                    </popovers>
                                </inline>
                                <!--<fullscreen-->
                                        <!--jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"-->
                                        <!--toolbar="[#format,-,subsuperscript#subscript,subsuperscript#superscript,-,edit#cut,edit#copy,edit#paste-plaintext,edit#paste-wordhtml,-,findreplace#find,findreplace#replace,-,undo#undo,undo#redo,-#justify,-,links#modifylink,links#unlink,links#anchor,-,#lists,-,spellcheck#checktext,-,misctools#specialchars,-,#styles,#paraformat,-,table#table,-,fullscreen#finish,-,control#close,control#save]">-->
                                    <!--<popovers jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">-->
                                        <!--<format-->
                                                <!--jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"-->
                                                <!--items="[format#bold,format#italic,format#underline]"-->
                                                <!--ref="format"/>-->
                                        <!--<justify-->
                                                <!--jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"-->
                                                <!--items="[justify#justifyleft,justify#justifycenter,justify#justifyright]"-->
                                                <!--ref="justify"/>-->
                                        <!--<lists-->
                                                <!--jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"-->
                                                <!--items="[lists#unordered,lists#ordered,lists#outdent,lists#indent]"-->
                                                <!--ref="lists"/>-->
                                        <!--<styles-->
                                                <!--jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"-->
                                                <!--items="styles:getStyles:styles-pulldown"-->
                                                <!--ref="styles"/>-->
                                        <!--<paraformat-->
                                                <!--jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"-->
                                                <!--items="paraformat:getFormats:paraformat-pulldown"-->
                                                <!--ref="paraformat"/>-->
                                    <!--</popovers>-->
                                <!--</fullscreen>-->
                                <tableEditOptions
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        toolbar="[table#insertcolumn-before,table#insertcolumn-after,table#removecolumn,-,table#insertrow-before,table#insertrow-after,table#removerow,-,table#mergecells-right,table#mergecells-down,table#mergecells,table#splitcell-horizontal,table#splitcell-vertical,-,table#selectrow,table#selectcolumn,-,table#ensureparagraph,-,table#modifytableandcell,table#removetable,-,undo#undo,undo#redo,-,table#exitTableEditing,-]"/>
                            </cui>
                        </uiSettings>
                    </text>
                </items>
            </column>
        </items>
    </content>
</jcr:root>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the basic AEM 6.1 jar where the toolbar shows only 3-5 buttons for Richtext dialog field even after creating proper rtePlugins node under the richtext field or using cq:inplaceEditing method. Try installing the AEM 6.1 Service Pack package and bug fix packages.You can find it on Adobe's site : https://www.adobeaemcloud.com/content/marketplace/marketplaceProxy.html?packagePath=/content/companies/public/adobe/packages/cq610/servicepack/AEM-6.1-Service-Pack-1. I have provided the path for SP1 which should be enough for your issue. You can also opt for SP2 plus Cumulative Bug fixes package(takes care of other issues). After that you will be able to see buttons corresponding to all the plugins configured by you under rtePlugins node.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you are using TouchUI. As such, there is no touchUI concept of an RTEeditor inside a dialog. RTE "by design", are inline in TouchUI. That said, if you double-click your inline RTE or click the spanner from the toolmenu, you are presented with a classicUI RTE inside a TouchUI dialog.

So in answering your question, the concept of having multiple RTE inside a dialog no longer exists, you probably need to rethink the design your component.

With reference to extending the toolbars on RTE you need to add uiSettings, both inline and fullscreen as required for the menu options you desire.

Here's a sample RTE dialog.xml with pretty much all plugins enabled:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
    helpPath="en/cq/current/wcm/default_components.html#Text"
    title="Text"
    xtype="tabpanel">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <tab1
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            anchor="100%"
            title="Text"
            xtype="panel">
            <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                <text
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    hideLabel="{Boolean}true"
                    name="./text"
                    useFixedInlineToolbar="{Boolean}true"
                    xtype="richtext">
                    <rtePlugins jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                        <edit
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            defaultPasteMode="wordhtml"
                            features="[cut,copy,paste-plaintext,paste-wordhtml]"
                            stripHtmlTags="{Boolean}true"/>
                        <findreplace
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            features="*"/>
                        <format
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            features="*"/>
                        <image
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            features="*"/>
                        <justify
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            features="*"/>
                        <links jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <linkDialogConfig
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                height="{Long}316">
                                <linkAttributes jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                    <linkAdvanced
                                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                        collapsed="{Boolean}true"
                                        collapsible="{Boolean}true"
                                        inputValue="advanced"
                                        name="./linkdialog/cq:adhocLinkTrackingTab"
                                        title="Link tracking"
                                        xtype="dialogfieldset">
                                        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                            <enable
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                attribute="enabletracking"
                                                fieldDescription="override analytics framework settings"
                                                fieldLabel="Custom link tracking"
                                                name="./linkdialog/cq:adhocLinkTrackingEnableTracking"
                                                xtype="checkbox">
                                                <listeners
                                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                    check="function(component){var dlg=component.findParentByType('rtelinkdialog');dlg.enableSCFields(component.checked);}"/>
                                            </enable>
                                            <events
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                attribute="adhocevents"
                                                fieldDescription="e.g.: event2, event7"
                                                fieldLabel="Include SiteCatalyst events"
                                                name="./linkdialog/cq:adhocLinkTrackingEvents"
                                                xtype="textfield"/>
                                            <evars
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                attribute="adhocevars"
                                                fieldDescription="e.g.: eVar1: pagedata.url, prop4: 'const'"
                                                fieldLabel="Include SiteCatalyst variables"
                                                name="./linkdialog/cq:adhocLinkTrackingEvars"
                                                xtype="textfield"/>
                                        </items>
                                    </linkAdvanced>
                                </linkAttributes>
                            </linkDialogConfig>
                        </links>
                        <lists
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            features="*"/>
                        <misctools
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            features="*">
                            <specialCharsConfig jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                <chars jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                    <copyright
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        entity="©"/>
                                    <trademark
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        entity="™"/>
                                    <registered
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        entity="®"/>
                                    <emDash
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        entity="—"/>
                                    <dagger
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        entity="†"/>
                                    <doubleDagger
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        entity="‡"/>
                                </chars>
                            </specialCharsConfig>
                        </misctools>
                        <paraformat
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            features="*">
                            <formats jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                <p
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    description="Paragraph"
                                    tag="p"/>
                                <h1
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    description="Heading 1"
                                    tag="h1"/>
                                <h2
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    description="Heading 2"
                                    tag="h2"/>
                                <h3
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    description="Heading 3"
                                    tag="h3"/>
                                <h4
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    description="Heading 4"
                                    tag="h4"/>
                                <h5
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    description="Heading 5"
                                    tag="h5"/>
                                <h6
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    description="Heading 6"
                                    tag="h6"/>
                            </formats>
                        </paraformat>
                        <spellcheck
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            features="*"
                            invalidStyle="background-color: #ffdddd;"/>
                        <styles
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            features="*">
                            <styles jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                <disclaimer
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    cssName="small"
                                    text="Disclaimer"/>
                            </styles>
                        </styles>
                        <subsuperscript
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            features="*"/>
                        <table
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            features="*"/>
                        <undo
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            features="*"/>
                    </rtePlugins>
                    <htmlRules jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                        <docType jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <typeConfig
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                useSemanticMarkup="{Boolean}true"/>
                        </docType>
                    </htmlRules>
                    <uiSettings jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                        <cui jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <inline
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                toolbar="[#format,-,#justify,-,#lists,-,links#modifylink,links#unlink,links#anchor,-,#styles,#paraformat,-,fullscreen#start,-,control#close,control#save]">
                                <popovers jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                    <format
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        items="[format#bold,format#italic,format#underline]"
                                        ref="format"/>
                                    <justify
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        items="[justify#justifyleft,justify#justifycenter,justify#justifyright]"
                                        ref="justify"/>
                                    <lists
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        items="[lists#unordered,lists#ordered,lists#outdent,lists#indent]"
                                        ref="lists"/>
                                    <styles
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        items="styles:getStyles:styles-pulldown"
                                        ref="styles"/>
                                    <paraformat
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        items="paraformat:getFormats:paraformat-pulldown"
                                        ref="paraformat"/>
                                </popovers>
                            </inline>
                            <fullscreen
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                toolbar="[#format,-,subsuperscript#subscript,subsuperscript#superscript,-,edit#cut,edit#copy,edit#paste-plaintext,edit#paste-wordhtml,-,findreplace#find,findreplace#replace,-,undo#undo,undo#redo,-#justify,-,links#modifylink,links#unlink,links#anchor,-,#lists,-,spellcheck#checktext,-,misctools#specialchars,-,#styles,#paraformat,-,table#table,-,fullscreen#finish,-,control#close,control#save]">
                                <popovers jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                    <format
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        items="[format#bold,format#italic,format#underline]"
                                        ref="format"/>
                                    <justify
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        items="[justify#justifyleft,justify#justifycenter,justify#justifyright]"
                                        ref="justify"/>
                                    <lists
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        items="[lists#unordered,lists#ordered,lists#outdent,lists#indent]"
                                        ref="lists"/>
                                    <styles
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        items="styles:getStyles:styles-pulldown"
                                        ref="styles"/>
                                    <paraformat
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        items="paraformat:getFormats:paraformat-pulldown"
                                        ref="paraformat"/>
                                </popovers>
                            </fullscreen>
                            <tableEditOptions
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                toolbar="[table#insertcolumn-before,table#insertcolumn-after,table#removecolumn,-,table#insertrow-before,table#insertrow-after,table#removerow,-,table#mergecells-right,table#mergecells-down,table#mergecells,table#splitcell-horizontal,table#splitcell-vertical,-,table#selectrow,table#selectcolumn,-,table#ensureparagraph,-,table#modifytableandcell,table#removetable,-,undo#undo,undo#redo,-,table#exitTableEditing,-]"/>
                        </cui>
                    </uiSettings>
                </text>
                <isRichTextFlag
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    ignoreData="{Boolean}true"
                    name="./textIsRich"
                    value="true"
                    xtype="hidden"/>
            </items>
        </tab1>
        <tab2
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            anchor="100%"
            title="Configurations"
            xtype="panel">
            <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                <noStackFlag
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    fieldLabel="Enable No Stack"
                    name="./noStack"
                    type="select"
                    xtype="selection">
                    <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                        <yes
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            text="Yes"
                            value="yes"/>
                        <no
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            text="No"
                            value="no"/>
                    </options>
                </noStackFlag>
            </items>
        </tab2>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

and the corresponding _cq_eeditConfig.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:EditConfig">
    <cq:inplaceEditing
        jcr:primaryType="cq:InplaceEditingConfig"
        active="{Boolean}true"
        configPath="../../dialog/items/tab1/items/text"
        editorType="text"/>
    <cq:listeners
        jcr:primaryType="cq:EditListenersConfig"
        afteredit="REFRESH_SELF"/>
</jcr:root>
```